# Query Table and Get Values Based on Conditional Statement

Tags: python, mysql

I am querying a table to get two values (yesterday_cy_day,yesterday_cy_day2). I also have another conditional statement under it to get "yesterday_cy_day".

What i want to do is:
If yesterdays date falls in any value in the list "extrareaddays" then run the first if statement. If the date is not in the list then run the second if statement below.

What i Tried:
I tried to  put the second block of code in an else statement but they both ran.

First code:

```
for extrareadday in extrareaddays:
if extrareadday in extrareadayday_date:
    for col, col2 in zip(extra_read_day1, extra_read_day2):
        yesterday_cy_day = col[8]
        yesterday_cy_day2 = col2[8]
        print("Saturday was an extra read day. We are going to use cycle 
days:", yesterday_cy_day, yesterday_cy_day2)
```

second code:

```
for col, col2 in zip(yesterday, friday):
    yesterday_cy_day = col[8]
    friday_cy_day = col2[8]
    if today_day == 'Monday' and today_day in col[18]:
        yesterday_cy_day = friday_cy_day
        print("Today is Monday so we will use Friday's cycle day")
    else:
        yesterday_cy_day = col[8]
        print("Today is not a monday so we will use yesterdays cycle day")
```

full code:

```
extrareaddays = ['2019-09-21', '2019-09-30', '2019-11-02', '2019-11-30', '2019-12-21']
# Format extra read day date as YYYY_MM-DD
extrareadayday_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=3)
extrareadayday_date = extrareadayday_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


yesterday_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday_date = yesterday_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(yesterday_date)

friday_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=4)
friday_date = friday_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


today_day = date.today()
today_day = today_day.strftime('%A')


yesterday_gregorian_q = """SELECT * FROM table
WHERE to_char(GREGORIAN_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '{}'""".format(yesterday_date)
mdwcursor.execute(yesterday_gregorian_q)

friday_gregorian_q = """SELECT * FROM table
WHERE to_char(GREGORIAN_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '{}'""".format(friday_date)
mdwcursor2.execute(friday_gregorian_q)

yesterday_cy_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=18)
yesterday_cy_date2 = date.today() - timedelta(days=17)
extra_read_day_gregorian_q = """SELECT * FROM table
WHERE to_char(GREGORIAN_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '{}'""".format(yesterday_cy_date)
extra_read_day_gregorian_q2 = """SELECT * FROM table
                WHERE to_char(GREGORIAN_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '{}'""".format(yesterday_cy_date2)


yesterday = mdwcursor.fetchall()
friday = mdwcursor2.fetchall()
extra_read_day1 = mdwcursor3.execute(extra_read_day_gregorian_q)
extra_read_day2 = mdwcursor4.execute(extra_read_day_gregorian_q2)

for extrareadday in extrareaddays:
    if extrareadday in extrareadayday_date:
        for col, col2 in zip(extra_read_day1, extra_read_day2):
            yesterday_cy_day = col[8]
            yesterday_cy_day2 = col2[8]
            print("Saturday was an extra read day. We are going to use cycle days:", yesterday_cy_day, yesterday_cy_day2)

for col, col2 in zip(yesterday, friday):
    yesterday_cy_day = col[8]
    friday_cy_day = col2[8]
    if today_day == 'Monday' and today_day in col[18]:
        yesterday_cy_day = friday_cy_day
        print("Today is Monday so we will use Friday's cycle day")
    else:
        yesterday_cy_day = col[8]
        print("Today is not a monday so we will use yesterdays cycle day")
```

Comment: Can you give us the example inputs and outputs? I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. It seems like it should be a simple `if` `else`

Comment: Don't use `.format()` to substitute into the SQL. Use parameters that `cursor.execute()` replaces.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb I am iterating through extrareaddays list. If the date is in the list then execute the first block of code. If it is not in the list then execute the second block of code.

Comment: I didn't rewrite all of your code but I blocked out how it should look for what you are trying to do as an answer. Let me know if you still don't understand how it should work. @ajburnett344

Answer (score 0):

Your primary code should look something like this calling to functions:

```py
for each_date in extrareaddays:
    if each_date in extrareadayday_date:
        first_thing(each_date)
    else:
        second_thing(each_date)
```

Now you'll need to define the functions above that as well, so:

```py
def first_thing(each_date):
    # the code you want to do for the first thing would be here
    # access the date for this loop using `each_date`

def second_thing(each_date):
    # the code you want to do for the second thing would be here
    # access the date for this loop using `each_date`
```